# Send path and argument to cmd

Tags: c#, process

I am tried to send path and argument to cmd.
I write in c#
But it does not work.
Any help appreciated.

My Code:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\phantom\phantom\bin\Debug\phantom";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName  = "cmd.exe";

startInfo.Arguments = " \"" + path + "\"  /c -phantomjs screentaker.js "; 
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: The executable path is not an Argument. Set that path to `startInfo.WorkingDirectory`

Comment: What's the exact command you are trying to run? Maybe `C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\phantom\phantom\bin\Debug\phantom.exe -phantomjs screentaker.js`?

Comment: yes i am trying to run code, as you write

Comment: See if my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

The executable path is not an Argument ,and the `FileName` shouldn't be `cmd.exe`. Try this:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\phantom\phantom\bin\Debug\phantom.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName  = path;

startInfo.Arguments = "-phantomjs screentaker.js"; 
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

If you insist using `cmd.exe`,this might work:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\phantom\phantom\bin\Debug\phantom.exe";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName  = "cmd.exe";

startInfo.Arguments = "/c " + path + " -phantomjs screentaker.js "; 
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: many thanks but does not working.i have to use cmd then i should go path and run script.